# Skipped installation of bin/classmap_generator.php ... by update of the Zend Framework 2 library

Tags: zend-framework2, updates, composer-php

When I try to update ZF2 in my project, I get this warning:

```
# php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.1.5)
    Loading from cache

    Skipped installation of bin/classmap_generator.php for package zendframework/zendframework: name conflicts with an existing file
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/common (Doctrine\Common >=2.1 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ext-intl (ext/intl for i18n features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Fallback random byte generator for Zend\Math\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavailable)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing pecl-weakref (Implementation of weak references for Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

What's going wrong here? What is the cause of these conflicts? How to update ZF2 correctly?

Comment: on which environment you are working?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.3 & Apache 2 & PHP 5.4.14

Comment: execute the command `composer.phar update` on terminal and then check.

Comment: `# php composer.phar update` returns
`Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files`

Comment: `# php composer.phar install` after it returns
`Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files`

Comment: always remember to read the documentation what changes has the latest version than previous and according to that you need to update that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually nothing to worry about, the most likely explanation is that you removed zendframework (or your entire vendor dir) and forgot to remove the bin/classmap_generator.php file, so it sees it's already there and skips the installation of that file.

Comment: I didn't remove anything. Or better: I actually "remove" everything, since it was a fresh project instance. So I cloned my project and executed the ZF2 composer commandos then.

Comment: Just checked: Actually the `vendor/bin/classmap_generator.php` is versioned. That means: when I'm cloning, It is also being checked out -- before the ZF2 is there. So, your assumption was right. What would be the recommend / most correct approach? Should `vendor/bin/classmap_generator.php` be added to the ignore list?

Comment: Generally speaking the whole vendor/ dir should be ignored by git yes.